# UIView background color does not take effect

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Can someone tell me why this is not working right?

I have these lines of code below within my table view cell for `tableView:didSelectAtIndexRowPath:` method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView viewWithTag:199]removeFromSuperview];

    CGSize cellSize = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].frame.size;

    UIView *subSelectionView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, (int)cellSize.width - 20, 100)];

    [subSelectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor  blueColor]];

    subSelectionView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    subSelectionView.layer.borderWidth = 1;

    subSelectionView.tag = 199;    

    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]addSubview:subSelectionView];
}
```

Notice the code:

```
[subSelectionView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor  blueColor]];
```

Obviously, I want to change the color of the subview that I added to the `UITableViewCell` but why is it not working ?

Comment: Make sure the `subSelectionView` is not covered by the table view cell's content view, because that seems to be what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jus reload the table after adding the subview on the table

```
[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]addSubview:subSelectionView];

[tableview reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following line to the start of the method

```
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
```

So ur method would be

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    [[tableView viewWithTag:199]removeFromSuperview];
    ....
}
```